# Is the default value of a declared variable always null?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I am declaring many different types in SQL and would like to know if the default value is always null for all types.

```
Declare @example int
Select @example
```

or

```
Declare @Example2 varchar(max)
Select @Example2
```

These are both null and most types I declare seem to be null by default, are there any exceptions to this?

Comment: In MS SQL Server, When a variable is first declared, its value is set to NULL. To assign a value to a variable, use the SET statement. This is the preferred method of assigning a value to a variable. A variable can also have a value assigned by being referenced in the select list of a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In MySQL:**

referred to MySQL documentations: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html

> To provide a default value for a variable, include a DEFAULT clause. The
>   value can be specified as an expression; it need not be a constant. If
>   the DEFAULT clause is missing, the initial value is NULL.

**In SQL Server**

As microsoft says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

> When a variable is first declared, its value is set to NULL.

But the story is a bit different when I have a table variable. suppose that I have a table variable like:

```
DECLARE @testTable AS TABLE
(
    Code INT,
    Firstname VARCHAR(100)
);
```

In this case we can not say that the @testTable is a variable which is initialised with NULL. In table variables, when they are declared, they are an empty table which contains no data.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of exceptions. Easy enough to test surely?

```
declare @bit bit

if @bit is null
    print 'null'

declare @float float
if @float is null
    print 'null'

declare @geo Geography
if @geo is null
    print 'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare any variable and does not set any value then its considered as an undefined value, that's why you will not get any exception of this that means you will get null always for all the variable without set any value.

Answer (score 0):

I Microsoft sql, the default value of the variable is always null. You can also specify the value in the declaration.  See the below example.

```
Declare @example int=34
Select @example
```

The result will be 34. I don't see any exception to this case anywhere for any other types.